# Animations in Maquette.js

Tags: javascript, animation, maquette

I've been looking further into using [maquette.js](https://github.com/AFASSoftware/maquette) as a virtual DOM library.
Looking at the [website](http://maquettejs.org/) the library has functionality to support animations when adding, removing, and updating DOM nodes.
But I cannot find any docs or API on what to do do achieve this.

To make it more concrete I have made a small sample below and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ktx1ddyf/4/).

```
var isPopupShown = false;

var togglePopup = function(){
 isPopupShown = !isPopupShown;   
}

var renderMaquette = function () {
  return h("div#container", [
    h("button",  {
      onclick: togglePopup
    }, ["Click me"]),
    isPopupShown ? h("div#popup") : null
  ]);
}
```

In the example, clicking the button will open the popup.
What I would like is that the popup would animate a fade-in when the node is added to the DOM and a fade-out when the node is removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation how animations work is still in progress.

There are currently two ways to do the animation.

**Velocity.js**

The easiest way is to use a library like [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/). For this to work you need to:

1. Add the velocity.js script to the page
2. Change `h("div#popup")` to `h("div#popup", {enterAnimation: fadeIn})`
3. Add the following javascript function

Code:

```
var fadeIn = function(element) {
  element.style.opacity = 0;
  Velocity.animate(element, {opacity: 1}, 1500, "ease-out");
};
```

You can view the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eoaz3s63/).

**CSS Transitions**

You can also use CSS transitions. They work the same as angularJS and react. You need to do the following:

1. Include the `css-transitions.min.js` script in your page. This
   script is also provided by maquette.
2. Change `h("div#popup")` to `h("div#popup", {enterAnimation: "fadeIn"})`
3. Change the createProjector call to `maquette.createProjector(document.body, renderMaquette, {transitions: cssTransitions});`
4. Add the following style declarations to the stylesheet:

Stylesheet:

```
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out opacity;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out opacity;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fadeIn.fadeIn-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You can view the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lymjg07p/1/)

Comment: The documentation for this can now be found [here](http://maquettejs.org/docs/animations.html). You can do experiments here using live code editors.